# Google translate sending back error in developer console

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I'm tying to set up google translate for a website, and about 30 seconds after you select language to Spanish I get this error in the developer console. Then the list box stops translating any further.

URL: https://www.here-today-gone-tomorrow.com/test.php

ERROR:

```
test.php:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at translateLanguage (test.php:49)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (test.php:16)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:4)
    at n.fn.init.n.fn.<computed> [as change] (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-select.js:656)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                    new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false }, 'google_translate_element');
                }
        
                function translateLanguage(lang) {
                    googleTranslateElementInit();
                    var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first');
                    if (!$frame.size()) {
                        alert("Error: Could not find Google translate frame.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    $frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains(' + lang + ')').get(0).click();
                    return false;
                }
        
                $(function(){
                    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in Firefox.

Comment: It works fine, just after 30 seconds after clicking on Spanish it will throw a error in the developers console. I concerned about the error.

Comment: As far as I can tell, sometimes, when switching languages, it fails to actually make the switch. There's no error when that happens. Trying to switching languages back to what it was before throws the error you're seeing. So if you start on English, switch to some other language and it fails, then try to switch back to English, you get the error.

Comment: Do you think it possible that google is throttling request? Because that's what it seems like.

Comment: OK it looks like the issue on the "fails on switching" is because the select box does not hold it value. After switching to Spanish it reverts to English on select box tiring to add cookie to resolve that but cant get it to work "hold Spanish or English value" here is what I've added, $(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    document.cookie = ('Language=(' + lang + ')') ;
});  But it fails